# How to compare generic types using a base class

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to compare generic types using a base class? eg:

```
propertyInfo.PropertyType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(List<BaseClass>))
```

I guess I could do the following, but is there a shorter way?

```
Type type = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>) && type.GetGenericArguments()[0].IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass))
```

Comment: You've got a one line solution that's clear and (presumably) already functions properly.  Why do you need anything shorter than that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_programming#Readability_of_source_code

Comment: Readability could be improved by moving these two lines to its separate method, say "isObjectChildOfBaseClass". This is the way taught to us by refactoring gurus.

Answer (score 0):

While your solution is one possibility, it doesn't account for when the target is a *subclass* of a closed generic type, such as `NamedList : List<BaseClass>, IKeyedItemCollection<string, BaseClass>`, since `IsGenericType` will return `false`.

Instead, however, when you're dealing with variance in generics, consider the [`.IsAssignableFrom` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
typeof(IEnumerable<BaseClass>).IsAssignableFrom(PropertyInfo.PropertyType)
```

This will return true even for a `DerivedList` where `DerivedList : List<DerivedClass>` and `DerivedClass : BaseClass`. Since `List` is *not* variance tolerant, however, it will not work for checking assignability to `List<BaseClass>`